# Does an Oni-Blooded variant heritage Tiefling potentially get +4 Wisdom?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits

The [*Tiefling*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling/) variant heritage *Oni-Blooded* gains a +2 Racial Bonus to Wisdom.
The *tiefling* variant ability, traded for the spell-like ability racial trait, entry no 90 grants:

> You gain an **additional** +2 racial bonus to your Wisdom score. *(emphasis mine)*

Does this mean an *Oni-Blooded Tiefling* that takes this variant ability gain a +4 Wisdom bonus, as the use of the word "additional" might imply, or is this intended for those *tiefling* who do not gain a Wisdom bonus from their standard racial modifiers?

---

*Info for the* tiefling *heritages can be* [more easily accessed here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fiendish-heritage), *but should be available by scrolling down past the racial traits on the main* tiefling *page.*

Comment: could you provide a link to the variant heritage? It doesn't figure among those in the Tiefling page you provided a link to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. It does.

However, keep in mind that the variant traits are presented as a random d100 roll on a table presented on the **Blood of Fiends** book, and that requires GM permission in the first place. Aasimars also have a similar table on the Blood of Angels book.

The tables have many abilities that are really strong, but there are some that you might consider as *useless* to your character. The objective of that roll is to represent inheritages that show different fiendish traits.

Those variant abilities are not accepted on Society game due to their nature, you cant tell which value was rolled when you created your character.

Comment: I wasn't aware they were not legal for PFS, but it makes complete sense that they aren't. Outside of that, the same section does also state that a DM can be consulted for selecting a specific ability. (Although I intend to roll, and was just wanting to confirm these effects stack)

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to make sure this information was clear. The last time I checked the heritages in the SRD, this information wasnt there.

Comment: I don't know how common it is, but none of my games use Tiefling/Aasimar alternate Abilities. They're often very powerful and the races themselves are already on the high end for PC's.

Answer (score 7):

## That [tiefling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling/) has a +4 bonus to its Wisdom score

A [tiefling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling/) that possesses the variant racial heritage oni-blooded *does* benefit from a result of 90 on the Table: Variant Tiefling Abilities that grants the tiefling a +2 racial bonus to its Wisdom score (for a total bonus of +4 to its Wisdom score).

The bonus to Wisdom that comes from being oni-blooded is unnamed—hence stacking with any other bonus—, and even were it a racial bonus, [racial bonuses stack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Racial-Bonus).

Comment: oh, that tidbit about racial stacking was unknown to me... guess i need to learn not to skip the basic pages of a new system.

Comment: @Mindwin O, it's phrased in such a way that it's extremely easy to overlook. Further, it come up so rarely that there's usually *no reason* even to remember the rule. (Off the top of my head, I know the *3.5e* template warbeast grants a creature a +1 racial bonus on Spot and Listen skill checks, for instance.)

Comment: some oracle mysteries add racial bonuses to stealth. don't have the ref at hand now, and don't remember which one.